# Hbase - Write operation

Tags: hadoop, hbase

In HBase, metadata is stored in catalog table i.e META tables. This tables is updated by HMaster during the start up or region splits or during load balancing of regions. Client wants to get some ROW ,get the region information from META table.

My question is , how this meta table is updated when we insert new rows in particular table ? For example , I executed a put command to insert a new row into existing table , how this row is reflected in Meta table , so that another client wants to fetch this row can pull the region info.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need for a META update unless you add a new region.

META keeps just a map of regions in the system (region-name -> machine)

A region contains a set of rows. let say that you have a table with 3 regions

- Region 1: [0, 3]
- Region 2: [4, 6]
- Region 3: [7, 9]

If you insert keys starting with a number between 0 and 3, your data will be inserted in Region 1.
If you insert keys starting with a number between 4 and 6, your data will be inserted in Region 2.
If you insert keys starting with a number between 7 and 9, your data will be inserted in Region 3.

when you ask for a particular key (put or get). META is consulted and the client is asking the question which regions contains the key X. And the region responsible to handle that range will be returned, and your operation is sent there.

so, there is no need to update META every insert you do. It is everything based on the key ranges.
(If you have a single region, that region will be responsible to handle all the keys, until it grows to large and it will split in two. Then the left region will contain keys lower then the middle key present in the original region and the right region will contain keys higher then the middle key present in the original region)